# Adding angular component to MapView.UI ESRI JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular

Stack: (Angular 13.x, ESRI JS API 4.22)

I have three components

1. Form (first thing the users see when the app loads)
2. Dashboard component ( it contains the component bellow )
3. mapview.component.ts (this initialize a MapView and add it to its
   container. it also loads when the application loads but it is not
   visible to the user yet.)
4. stats.component.ts (this component is
   just a div with some info-cards. The data in the cards is dynamic, it
   gets generated when the user submit the form)

So the work flow is:
1-user fill the form
2- the dashboard component shows up, 3- layer gets added to the map.

What I'd like to do next is something like:

```
let statComponent  = statsComponent();

this.MapView.ui.add (statsComponent, 'top-left')
```

Has anybody been able to dynamically display a component within the MapView.UI?